# Erro ao usar o Sequelize utilizando MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

Código para estabelecer a conexão com o banco de dados:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
// Conexão com o banco de dados MySQL
  const sequelize = new Sequelize('postagens', 'root', 'mafikgod123@', {
    host: "localhost",
    dialect: "mysql"
  })

module.exports = {
  Sequelize: Sequelize,
  sequelize: sequelize
}
```

Modelo `post`:

```
const db = require('./db')

const Post = db.sequelize.define('postagens', {
    titulo: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    conteudo: {
        type: db.Sequelize.TEXT
    }
})

Post.sync({force: true})
```

Erro:

> ```
> Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
>     at Promise.tap.then.catch.err (C:\Users\wesley\Desktop\CURSO-NODE\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:133:19)
>     at tryCatcher (C:\Users\wesley\Desktop\CURSO-NODE\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
>     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\wesley\Desktop\CURSO-NODE\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:517:31)
>     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\wesley\Desktop\CURSO-NODE\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:574:18)
>     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\wesley\Desktop\CURSO-NODE\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:619:10)
>     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\wesley\Desktop\CURSO-NODE\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:695:18)
>     at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\wesley\Desktop\CURSO-NODE\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
>     at _drainQueue (C:\Users\wesley\Desktop\CURSO-NODE\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
>     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\wesley\Desktop\CURSO-NODE\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
>     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Users\wesley\Desktop\CURSO-NODE\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
>     at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
>     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
>     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adaptado do [Stack Overflow em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50547109/7445826):

Se você estiver utilizando o MySQL 8x, o problema está na nova forma de autenticação, que não é suportada pela maioria dos *drivers* atuais.

Para corrigir, você deve modificar a forma de autenticação. Para isso, terá que executar o seguinte comando no MySQL:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Sendo `password` a nova senha que você usará para acessar o usuário `root`. Se você estiver utilizando outro usuário, basta modificar o `root` no comando acima pelo usuário desejado.

> Não se esqueça de fazer um *backup* se estiver trabalhando com dados de um ambiente de produção.